# What is stable version for jasperreports-maven-plugin?

Tags: maven, jasper-reports

In my project, I am using *Maven 3.0.4* and using *JasperReports 5.1.0*. To compile the *JRXML*  file, using the *jasperreports-maven-plugins*. I have the *jasperreports-maven-plugin* with version 1.0-beta-2. Since it was beta version (1.0-beta-2) Can i know, what is stable version of *jasperreports-maven-plugin* available to be use?

Below the plugin used in my pom.xml file

```xml
<properties>
      <jasperreports.version>5.1.0</jasperreports.version>
</properties>

<build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-beta-2</version>
            <configuration>
               <sourceDirectory>src/main/resources/reports</sourceDirectory>
               <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/reports</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <!-- Need to bind to the compile phase cuz the reports uses classes under target/classes. The default is the generate-resources phase. -->
                  <phase>compile</phase>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>compile-reports</goal>
                  </goals>
               </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
               <dependency>
                  <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
                  <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
                  <version>${jasperreports.version}</version>
               </dependency>
               <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                  <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                  <version>2.0.1</version>
                  <scope>compile</scope>
                  <optional>true</optional>
               </dependency>
            </dependencies>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
```

Comment: Seems to me that [1.0-beta-3-SNAPSHOT](http://svn.codehaus.org/mojo/trunk/mojo/jasperreports-maven-plugin/pom.xml) is last. It is from the trunk

Comment: But you can get the source code :)

Comment: And the tags are [here](http://svn.codehaus.org/mojo/tags/)

Comment: The [asperreports-maven-plugin-1.0-beta-2](http://svn.codehaus.org/mojo/tags/jasperreports-maven-plugin-1.0-beta-2/) is latest from the tag

Answer (score 27):

Forget about the official maven plugin. I've been using [alexnederlof's Jasper report maven plugin](https://github.com/alexnederlof/Jasper-report-maven-plugin) for a long time and works like a charm.

You can find more info at github:

> The original jasperreports-maven-plugin from org.codehaus.mojo was a
>   bit slow. This plugin is 10x faster. I tested it with 52 reports which
>   took 48 seconds with the original plugin and only 4.7 seconds with
>   this plugin.

and in his [blog](http://alex.nederlof.com/blog/2011/09/11/a-10x-faster-jasper-maven-plugin/):

> The original plug-in is created in Java 4, works single-threaded and
>   the last time any committed to the repo was (at time of writing) 31st
>   of August, 2009. Not really an active project it seems.