# Generate .jasper with maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, jasper-reports, maven-plugin

I´m looking to improve the performance of my application, which has two types of reports, and compile then at execution time like this :

```
  final JasperDesign design = JRXmlLoader.load(input);

  final JasperReport compiledReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(design);
```

This code executes every time when the user wants to see the report on the app.
To avoid this, I´m trying to execute the compilation of the .jrxml through maven jasperreports plugin, but it doesn't work, and there isn't an error on console.
The .jasper files don't appear in my directory "outputDirectory".

```
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
         <execution>
              <phase>compile</phase>
            <inherited>false</inherited>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile-reports</goal>
            </goals>
         </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
         <sourceDirectory>src/main/resources/reports</sourceDirectory>
        <outputDirectory>src/main/resources/reports/jasper</outputDirectory>
            <compiler>net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRJdtCompiler</compiler>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: check this https://bowerstudios.com/node/976

Comment: Thanks Deendayal. I follow this page, add the dependencies and exclusions. My app strarts up but the folder "jasper" is still empty... I dont find the problem..

Comment: and you are not getting any error in the build log?

Comment: No, any error.. the start up is correct.

Comment: Consider migrating to `jasperreports-plugin` instead: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18495377/1743880

Comment: try with jasperreports-plugin, the folder jasper continues empty.. Its very extrange

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but this happened to me when I defined the plugin in the `<pluginManagement>` section of the POM instead of in `<plugins>`.

Answer (score 1):

This was the pom config I used

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-beta-2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile-reports</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!--  jrxml file  directory-->
                        <sourceDirectory>src\\main\\resources\\reports\\template</sourceDirectory>
                        <sourceFileExt>.jrxml</sourceFileExt>
                        <compiler>net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRJavacCompiler</compiler>
                        <!--  Destination for jasper file -->
                        <outputDirectory>src\\main\\resources\\reports\\jasper</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <!-- These plugins are used to specify correct version for jrxml xml validation -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
                    <version>4.5.0</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.16</version>
                </dependency>

            </dependencies>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```